# Very low stacking height PCB connector

Tags: pcb, connector, pcb-assembly

I need to stack two [PCBs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printed_circuit_board) together, but the stacking height is extremely critical. In terms of board-to-board connectors, the best I could come up with was SAMTEC GFZ series.

What other solutions can be recommended to stack two different PCBs? I need to have very low stacking height (less than 2 mm, the lower the better), and about 100 connections.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SlimStack and/or PMC connectors might be useful alternatives, it depends a bit on the pin pitch that you can use:

https://www.molex.com/en-us/products/connectors/board-to-board-connectors

I have a card with the PMC connector, and it is really tiny:[image: FOXg20 card with Molex PMC connector]

Comment: Slimstack looks very interesting. One thing that is of concern with it is the durability rating. It has maximum 30 mating cycles durability.

Answer (score 4):

Panasonic P4 series, 100 way socket and header parts numbers are AXK700127G and AXK800125WG respecitively.

Total mating height of 1.5 mm

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how much space you want to take up but you can use standard header pin arrays.  solder them to 1 board, drill through the other board (1 hole per pin) put the female header on the back side of the board (side facing away from the other board) lined up with the holes.  The spacing between the boards could be arbitrarily small, it will only be defined by the thickness of the plastic spacer on the header pins which comes in various sizes.

For example:

[50 Pin header - 1mm molding](http://www.sullinscorp.com/drawings/159_SMH100-LP_E-D___-ST-BK,_11195-A.pdf) (~1mm board to board spacing)

[50 Pin Female Socket](http://www.sullinscorp.com/drawings/174_SFM210-LP_E-D___-S_-BK,_11200-A.pdf)

Comment: How do you attach the female socket with its pins sticking in the air?  Most of these aren't bottom-entry.  The linked one has a 2.1mm stacking height.  I do know that you can get through-board SMD male headers, though.

Comment: Most i've run into, are actually top or bottom entry, including the one one i linked as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Go look at part search on [Hirose Connectors](http://www.hirose-connectors.com/), they have a lot of different choices to offer for the different stacking heights.