# Unusual Surface Mount Package (with notches) - how to mount / solder?

Tags: pcb, soldering, surface-mount, prototyping, dip

I have recently acquired an electronics component that I was expecting to have a "normal" surface mount foot that I could solder.

Instead, what is has is a very thick section that has a 0.50mm semi-circular notch (see picture):

[image: SMD Device mounting notches]

What is the appropriate way to mount a device like this? Are the notches designed to take a pin of some kind?

The notches are a standard 2.54mm pitch, and the row spacing is 19mm - I haven't found any kind of socket that would take a component of this size, so I'm assuming it would need to be soldered directly to the PCB?

Comment: For further information: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/45733/ideas-for-attaching-connecting-stacking-one-pcb-onto-another-with-no-gap and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60645/how-are-these-pcb-pads-made/60646#60646

Comment: Yes, normal surface mount techniques apply, or you should be able to solder it by hand with an iron.  Beware if doing paste based SMT that a thicker than usual stencil may be recommended to supply enough solder.

Comment: This type of contacts is called **castellation**.

Answer (score 4):

They *can* take a pin, but they can also be soldered directly to a square or rectangular pad beneath them much as a SMD passive would. This particular form factor allows for both through-hole (with a bit of work) and surface-mount in the same package.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio - how would one do a through-hole mounting with this? Solder the pin to the package?

Comment: Maybe.  I'd probably drop a row of header pins for each side into the board, set the module between, and solder both at once to avoid alignment problems.  But then, I'd opt for the surface mount possibility over through hole anyway.

Comment: The alignment issue can be solved by using a perfboard, and pin retainment can be solved by using pins with ridges. But the header row is a good solution.