# EagleCad printed circuit board "mount hole" part

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, surface-mount

I want to produce a printed circuit board in EagleCad. Below picture is and example circuit.

[image]

I want to add M1 and M2 holes in my circuit for soldering, but I do not know what their names in real life and in EagleCad software. Also, I want to be able to make their radius 5mm long. How can I implement this in EagleCad.

Comment: Note that you can create vias and set their diameter and annular ring, so a specific component should not be needed.

Answer (score 2):

> names in real life

They are called castellated holes.

Complexity Levels (or Class levels)
There are several factors that contribute to the complexity of a castellated hole. The main critical design attributes are:

• Hole size

• Number of holes per board

• Single hole or multiple hole designs

• Surface finish

Source: 
http://www.hitech.com.mk/en/technology/castell

Example of creating the castellated holes is here: [Designing castellations/half holes using EAGLE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/198577/designing-castellations-half-holes-using-eagle)

Comment: M1 and M2 are not castellated holes, they're just plain old holes. I do think however you should hold this answer for his/her next question, and it's a more interesting question/answer indeed.

Comment: That was hilarious!

Comment: @orkun You appear to have a pretty snarky attitude for someone asking for gratis help.

Answer (score 0):

Those are plated holes, and there's a library of hole components in Eagle.

Comment: What should I type in search area Sir? Plated hole is not available. Sorry for my knowledge about Eagle.

Comment: What about searching for "hole"?

Comment: Approximately 100 results show up.

Comment: Search for "via"

Comment: Wow! 100 results! Soo many, you might need to try a few – they all have descriptions. Seriously, this website is not for holding your hand, @orkun, but for giving you the right direction.

Comment: I think you should not answer questions that you dont know. @marcus

Comment: I know the answer to the question you asked, which was "which type of device in eagle should I use, and how to find it". I can't read your mind and tell you which specific type of hole you need, so really, giving you a list of candidates shouldn't really pose a problem for you. For heck's sake, there's the diameter even in the *name* of these components.